# Minimising number of computations in fuzzy matching and a for loop

Tags: r

I am currently trying to find some potential duplicates in a large data set (500,000+ lines)  using fuzzy  matching. There are three  main parts to this code:

1. A function that I have written that identifies the most like  potential duplicate in a data set (by returning a score - it selects the highest score).
2. A function that identifies the position of the record that is the most likely to be a duplicate.
3. A for loop  that runs  both  of the  functions above for every  record and returns  values in the  `DupScore` column and the  `positionBestMatch`  column.

An example of a resulting  dataset is below:

```
   Name:     DOB:         DupScore    positionbestMatch
   Ben       6/3/1994     15          3
   Abe       5/5/2005     11          5
   Benjamin  6/3/1994     15          1 
   Gabby     01/01/1900   10          6
   Abraham   5/5/2005     11          2
   Gabriella 01/01/1900   10          4
```

The for loop to calculate these  scores looks a bit like this (`scorefunc` and `position func` are self 
 written functions):

```
for (i in c(1:length(df$Name))) {
  df$dupScore[i]<-scorefunc[i]
  df$positionBestMatch[i]<-positionfunc[i]
}
```

Obviously, on a data set with so many rows, this  loop is time consuming and computationally intensive as it loops through  each row. How can I edit my for loop so  that :

1. When a `DupScore` is calculated for a row, it will also insert the  score not only in the `[i]` row, but also the row of `positionbestMatch` ?
2. And have the loop  only run  for those with empty `DupScore` and `positionBestMatch` values.

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `while` loop

```
all_inds <- seq_len(nrow(df))
i <- all_inds[1]

while (length(all_inds) > 1) {
   i <- all_inds[1]
   df$dupScore[i]<-scorefunc[i]
   df$positionBestMatch[i]<-positionfunc[i]
   df$dupScore[df$positionBestMatch[i]] <- df$dupScore[i] 
   all_inds <- setdiff(all_inds, c(i, df$positionBestMatch[i]))
}
```

But this will keep some empty values for `df$positionBestMatch`.